# Exterior Product on de rham homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

Given a smooth manifold $M$ and its differential graded commutstive de Rham algebra $(\Omega(M),d,\wedge)$, the wedge product $\wedge$ can be projected onto the de Rham cohomology $(H_{dR}(M),\wedge)$.

What is an elegant way to proof that the wedge product is, indeed, well defined on $H_{dR}(M)$?

Comment: Exterior derivative is a graded derivation on the algebra of differential forms.

Comment: Is this comment related to the question? If yes, please explain this a bit more in detail

Comment: I'm saying  that $d(\alpha\wedge\beta)=d\alpha\wedge\beta+(-1)^{\text{deg}\alpha}\alpha\wedge d\beta$.  Therefore, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are closed, their wedge product is closed, and if one is exact their wedge product will also be exact.